# Error in na.fail.default (list(Training = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes", : missing values in object

Tags: r

I am trying to run a **xgbTree** model

```
fit.xgb_train <- train(Training~., 
                  data=scaled_t,
                  method = "xgbTree",
                  metric= "Accuracy",
                  preProc = c("center", "scale"), 
                  trControl = myControl,
                  tuneGrid = tune_grid,
                  tuneLength = 10)
```

I get this error code:

```
Error in na.fail.default(list(Training = c("yes", "yes", "yes", "yes",  : 
  missing values in object
```

Comment: Please share your data using `dput(df)`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.